# retrieving changed url from address bar in the controller in grails

Tags: java

In my website which is developed in grails I want the search to be redirected to specific page.... In url mapping, I have redirected the various searches like grails application development, mobile application development to an action inside the controller....
Within the action, I want to extract that complete url which the user will refer to if he wants to search for grails application develoment in my website...
For example- http:/mysite.com/grails-application-developmemt.... 
I want to extract this url in the action of my controller through some java method or anything else so that I can enable specific searching feature for my website

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really looking for.
But i hope this might help.

if you want custom url mapping then you can define it on **UrlMappings.groovy**:

```
"/$query?"(controller: "search", action: 'index', view: '/search')
```

And your action will receive additional parameter named "query"

```
class SearchController {
    def index(){
        String myquery = params.query
        .....
    }
}
```

then url will look like:

```
http://yoursite.com/grails-application-developmemt
```